# SQL SELECT in PHP function

Tags: php, sql, function, select

I have seen some questions and answers on here but none have given me the solution I am looking for. I hope you all could help me, I am kind off new to this whole PHP and SQL stuff.

What I am trying to do is create a PHP function that I can echo or print in a webpage. I will need multiple functions on the website to echo or print the id and product names.

So far I got this code to work:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbName";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbName";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["Id"]. " Product: " . $row["Product"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This code is from the W3C schools website and modified. When using this code I get the results on top of my page.

Now looking around here I came across this code which looks like something that might just work for me.

```
function sidebar_query(){
        $rValue = "";
        $query = ("SELECT sidebarposts FROM table;");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $rValue = $row['sidebarposts'];
        }
    return $rValue;
    }
```

After some messing around I came up with this...

```
function id(){
        $rValue = "";
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM dbName;");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $rValue = $row['Id'];
        }
    return $rValue;
    } else {
       echo "Null";
    }
```

And well, this didn't work. I did use `<?php id(); ?>` to trigger the function in the webpage code. But with no luck. It gives me NULL. So there is something going on. But I can't seem to figure it out.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

// little update: It looks like the bd is not called upon in the function. Because the some SELECT but without the function works just fine...

Comment: Why do you suddenly change from using `mysqli` (good) to using `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated and to be removed?

Comment: I think that's because I just copied and pasted this function to see if it worked. I have read about mysqli and the deprecated mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

Call as (For instant solution)

```
<?php echo id(); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php id(); ?>
```

AND REPLACE HERE

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH);
```

Comment: Used  `<?php echo id(); ?>` didn't work. Just say's Null again.

Comment: If you mend this:

`function id(){
    $rValue = "";
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM MirrorWebProductsExpanded;");
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
 if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH)){
        $rValue = $row['Id'];
    }
 else {
   return "Null";
}
return $rValue;
} `

that didn't work....

Comment: why are you mixing up mysql and mysqli , replace all with a one , use mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: That would probably be due to the fact that I was using two scripts. Still trying this whole PHP and SQL thing out. Your mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); did not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you enabled both - the mysql and the mysqli API?
If not - try the following:

```
function id(){
    $rValue = "";
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM dbName;");
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $rValue = $row['Id'];
    }
return $rValue;
} else {
   echo "Null"
}
```

Comment: I copied your code in my PHP header, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have return and an echo in the same function.

You should either use **return** :

```
if(){ ...
   return $rValue;
} else {
   return null;
}
```

or with **echo**

```
if(){ ...
   echo $rValue;
} else {
   echo '';
}
```

Comment: using `echo` or `return` both times still same problem.

Comment: You should try with : `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) `

Comment: @Alex.C this doesn't work. To bad. Looked promising because of the ASSOC which is also in the W3C code.

Comment: Also, you don't pass the connection to the query function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  function id(){
        $rValue = "";
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM dbName;");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $rValue = $row['Id'];
        }
        else {
       echo "Null";
    }
    return $rValue;
 }
```

Comment: Do you have an open mysql_connect ?

Comment: If by that you mean, do you have a connection with your sql database. Then yes.